# Rad Studio 2010 SOAP web service not functioning correctly with HTTPS

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, https

I have a web service that runs correctly with just http enabled on the server (IIS7), every time I call it I get an answer back as expected. However when I enable https, start up the client and call the web service it does as it's told, but if I don't call it for about 2mins and then call it, it will produce this exception.

"The handle is in the wrong state for the requested operation - URL:http://localhost:443/...". The rest of the URL is just the soap extension.

Looking at the exception I see that it's trying to use http through port 443 which is for https, but I have no idea why it is doing this, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just figured out what the problem was. You need to set the poPublishLocationAsSecure property of the WSDLHTMLPublish1 object to true!

*Btw embarcadero, your documentation on things is bloody awful, great product when you figure out how things work, but only to be let down with your sub-par support!